# Can you cancel the "cut" command in the orchard?

Tags: banished

I accidently clicked the "cut" button of one of my orchards and the farmers have started to cut down my precious fruit trees. I want them to stop. Is there a way to cancel this command?

Comment: I did the same thing once and couldn't get them to stop.  But I'd just bought a new seed and so at least I had a good place to plant the new tree type.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can. Same with harvest command on farms. As soon as you tell them to do it, it's too late. You best bet is to reload a recent save to "undo" it.